# How to get data from ellipses in selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to automate the compose email flow in gmail. where I have to select the label as social while composing the mail. below are the steps to select that label.

1- Click on ellipses

2- Hover on label option

3- Search/select social label from options

4- Click on apply.

I have clicked on ellipses but when I try to find label element it gives an error as "No such element."

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow. In order for the community to pinpoint the issue, please add what steps/piece of code you've tried and which step are you failing. It will help us give you the correct solution.

Comment: Update the question with the relevant HTML

Answer (score 0):

As you have not added your code which you have tried so I can't help in your code but I have tried to automate the same in my system and it is working fine. I did not write the steps of login. I have started from click on compose button and ends after selecting the Social label. Please find below the locators and code which I have used:

```
By composeButton = By.xpath("//div[text()='Compose']");
By ellipses = By.cssSelector("div[data-tooltip='More options']");
By label = By.xpath("//div[text()='Label']");
By labelInput = By.cssSelector("input.bqf");
By socialTag = By.cssSelector("div[title='Social']");

driver.findElement(composeButton).click();
driver.findElement(ellipses).click();
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
action.moveToElement(driver.findElement(label)).build().perform();
driver.findElement(labelInput).sendKeys("Social");
driver.findElement(socialTag).click();
```